# How to apply a variable with color value in style:color attribute as below <span style="color:{{alert.alertColor}}">

Tags: html, jsp

```
<span style="color:{{variable}}"></span>
```

This is the HTML. This method is not working and show a syntax error in jsp.
Variable is returning from java. How to achieve this dynamic color?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for Expression Language (EL) is wrong. It should look something like this:

```
<span style="color:${variable}"></span>
```

Proper syntax to access your variable in JSP is like this: **${x}** not like this **{{x}}**. 
For more information read official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjddd/index.html) or this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm).
If you still have struggle, please copy there your java code where you fill your model/request with your variable.

Comment: Already tried style="color:${variable}. same result. syntax not acceping. marque is going without any color.  style="color:#FF0000 is working. dynamic substitution through varible is not working..

Comment: Could you please send there your JSP code which ends in syntax error? Because code in my comment is syntax valid. Also can you try put `<c:set var="variable" value="#FF0000"/>` above your span element to be sure, that there is really value in your variable? Thanks.  Edit: You need to have included jstl core library for setting that variable like this `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` @Prakash